# Life Time Of : ViewBag, TempData, ViewData and Session

Tags: asp.net-mvc

These Are Useful to store Data. Session are destroyed by time that is set by webserver. Viewbag and ViewData work as view as work and destroyed while redirects. How about TempData? Or more useful information.

Comment: hold your session in a database. tempdata only lasts for one page - ie, transfer data from one page to another. viewbag/viewdata are reset on page refresh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here Is Mechanism and more info [Data-Passing-Mechanism-in-MVC-Architecture](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/827059/Data-Passing-Mechanism-in-MVC-Architecture)

Answer (score 9):

The lifetime of `TempData` is only available on the current `Request` and the subsequent `Request`.

You may want to read the article below.

http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications

Comment: Note to modern readers: TempData's lifetime is different as of .NET Core.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63818038/5405967) for details.

Comment: [Even in the old World, TempData lasted longer, than one request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12815759/2441442), found out today the hard way