# How to clear specific TempData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to clear specific TempData in asp.net mvc. I am using more than two `TempData` var. I can to clear specific some of them.

```
TempData["USD"] = "updated";
TempData["EUR"] = "updated";
TempData["PKR"] = "updated";
```

`TempData.Clear()` will clear all TempData, how to do this for specific

Comment: `TempData["whateveryouwanttoclear"] = string.empty` or `null`?

Comment: Why do you need to clean it up?  Perhaps `Cache` is a better choice than `TempData`?

Comment: @Kritner not working

Comment: after one request tempdata will dispose itself then why you need to clear if

Comment: I am using this wihin requestt

Comment: if u need within request why do you need tempdata

Comment: I am using this a flag

Answer (score 26, accepted):

just this worked for me fine, only removed `TempData["USD"]`

```
TempData.Remove("USD");
```

Comment: How is this any different from @user3060520 's answer?

Answer (score 3):

```
var value = filterContext.Controller.TempData["value"];
filterContext.Controller.TempData.Remove("value");
```

Comment: this is not removing

Comment: Could you also check [TempData won't destroy after second request](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12815759/3060520)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way of removing **TempData**, when using dynamic key name,

Eg:

```
UserModel model = new UserModel(); //Declare
model.UserId = 12;
model.UserName = "Karthik";
TempData["UserModel_" + model.UserId] = model.UserModel; //Assign
```

To get value from **TempData**,

```
UserModel model = new UserModel(); //Declare
model.UserId = 12;
model = (UserModel)TempData["UserModel_" + model.UserId];  //Get
TempData.Keep("UserModel_" + model.UserId);
```

Remove **TempData** without knowing dynamic key name,

```
foreach (var key in TempData.Keys.ToList())
{
    TempData.Remove(key);   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is I need.

Comment: Why not just use `TempData.Clear()` for the last bit?