# Having issues with tempdata not being cleared

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, tempdata

In my application I have created a base controller. All the other controller derives from `BaseController`

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Base/
    public void Warning(string message)
    {
        TempData.Add(Alerts.WARNING, message);
    }
    public void Success(string message)
    {
        TempData.Add(Alerts.SUCCESS, message);
    }

    public void Information(string message)
    {
        TempData.Add(Alerts.INFORMATION, message);
    }

    public void Error(string message)
    {
        TempData.Add(Alerts.ERROR, message);
    }
}
```

No if I derive any other controller from `BaseController` it is possible to do this

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
   Success("This is a success Alert");
}
```

Now in `_alert partial view` I check the tempdata and growl it using [Toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr).

**_alerts partial view**

```
@if (TempData.ContainsKey(Alerts.SUCCESS))
{
    foreach (var value in TempData.Values)
    {
        <script>    
            toastr.success("@value.ToString()");
        </script>

    }


}

@if (TempData.ContainsKey(Alerts.ERROR))
{
    foreach (var value in TempData.Values)
    {
        <script>

            toastr.error("@value.ToString()");
        </script>
    }
}

@if (TempData.ContainsKey(Alerts.INFORMATION))
{
    foreach (var value in TempData.Values)
    {
        <script>

            toastr.warning("@value.ToString()");
        </script>
    }
}

@if (TempData.ContainsKey(Alerts.WARNING))
{
    foreach (var value in TempData.Values)
    {
        <script>    
            toastr.warning("@value.ToString()");
        </script>
    }
}
```

this `_alert` partial view is renderd in my `_layout` view. Which is the main layout of the application.

All all the pages use that layout.

**Problem:**

The problem i'm facing is, once I send the message from controller, for example:

```
Success("This is a success message");
```

I get a nice message in browser. But everytime I go to next page I get the same message, as it still stays in my `TempData`.

What can I do to solve this issue?

I probably have to clear the temp data, but where?

I tried clearing TempData from view:
but it doesn't allow me. I get error on browser saying I can only perform assign, increment, decrement and creating object and things like that but not `TempData.Clear();`. Also, it would not be good idea to perform clearing TempData in client side, would it?

Comment: TempData persists until read. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953302/tempdata-is-not-clearing-as-expected it suggests changing the if statement from TempData.ContainsKey to TempData[] as this counts as a read

Comment: @Cookie if TempData is cleared when it is read, then wouldn't TempData[Alerts.INFORMATION] != null be counted as reading? If its true then my message which i'm showing inside the if statement, what would happen to that?

Comment: "growl it using Toastr" <- As a developer it both amuses and concerns me that this is a valid line of text.

Comment: @Rondles Haha I didn't know the proper way to say it...Probably Alert using toastr?

Comment: No, please read the other anser, TempData.ContainsKey is not causing a read, accessing TempData with a key is

Answer (score 1):

Could you try changing all usages of ContainsKey to a not null check?

Change this

```
@if (TempData.ContainsKey(Alerts.INFORMATION))
{
}
```

To

```
@if (TempData[Alerts.INFORMATION] != null)
{
}
```

Appearantly the TempData is only cleared when it is read and calling ContainsKey does not count as a read.
Relevant Stackoverflow article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953302/tempdata-is-not-clearing-as-expected)

**Update**: tried following code with success.
Every time I reload, the `TempData["S"]` is null and refilled with the message (so it is the expected behaviour).

BaseController

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public void Success(string message)
    {
        TempData.Add("S", message);
    }
}
```

HomeController

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    Success("This is a success Alert");
    return View();
}
```

View

```
@if (TempData["S"] != null)
{
    foreach (var value in TempData.Values)
    {
        @value.ToString()
    }
}
```

Comment: if TempData is cleared when it is read, then wouldn't `TempData[Alerts.INFORMATION] != null` be counted as reading? If its true then my message which i'm showing inside the if statement, what would happen to that?

Comment: I gave it a shot, but now my message doesn't show up.

Comment: I tried the code myself and for me it works with the not null check, see my updated answer.

Comment: Also thing to keep in mind `Furthermore, if you use RedirectResult or RedirectToRouteResult, they will persist even if they are read.` So in that case would it still work if you use `RedirectResult` or `RedirectToRouteResult` as return type?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have done the trick

```
@if (TempData.ContainsKey(Alerts.SUCCESS))
{
    foreach (var value in TempData.Values)
    {
        <script>    
            toastr.success("@value.ToString()");
        </script>

    }
    TempData.Remove(Alerts.SUCCESS);

}
```

but I still don't know if it is a good idea to clear TempData from view like I have done.

Suggestions?